# Mandatory things to be added in .env file in UNIX

Tags: unix, env

I am creating a .env file on UNIX server.

Please recommend me what mandatory things should be added into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to create `.env` file unless there is a specific need for it. The best contents for this file, in fine Zen tradition, would be no contents and no file.